# how to define an evil-operator to move forward/backward a text-object?

Tags: evil, commands, motion

I am trying to define a function that moves to the begin/end of current text-object.

**First** - I define an operator:

```
(evil-define-operator evil-forward-text-object (beg end type)
  "move to end of text object"
  (if (eq type 'block)
      (evil-apply-on-block #'evil-forward-text-object beg end nil)
    (goto-char end)))
```

In this case I need to press `M-w i )` to move forward a bracket.
There will be an `i` or `a`, it is troublesome to type `a` or `i`,
and there is no difference between `i` and `a`.

**Next** - I try to set the keymap:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "M-w")
  evil-inner-text-objects-map)
```

This works in some cases, such as `M-w p` or `M-w o`
(forward a kebab-style Lisp symbol).
But in most cases it does not work - for example, `M-w )` and `M-w "`.

How can I define a command such as I described?

Answer (score 1):

finally i use `read-key-sequence` to read text-object then execute it:

```
;; move over text object
(evil-define-motion evil-forward-text-object
  (count &optional text-object)
  "move to the end of following input text-object define 
in evil-inner-text-objects-map ."
  (unless text-object
      (setf text-object
            (let ((key (read-key-sequence "text-object:")))
              (lookup-key evil-inner-text-objects-map key))))
  (let* ((region (funcall text-object count))
         (end (nth 1 region)))
    (goto-char end)))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "M-w")
  #'evil-forward-text-object)

(evil-define-motion evil-backward-text-object
  (count &optional text-object)
  "move to the begin of following input text-object define 
in evil-inner-text-objects-map ."
  (unless text-object
      (setf text-object
            (let ((key (read-key-sequence "text-object:")))
              (lookup-key evil-inner-text-objects-map key))))
  (let* ((region (funcall text-object count))
         (start (nth 0 region)))
    (goto-char start)))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "M-b")
  #'evil-backward-text-object)
```

Comment: Please edit your original answer to include this part rather than submit two answers.

Comment: i think they are 2 different aproach. it is better to keep in 2 answer.

Answer (score 0):

in `evil-commands.el` state:

> Text objects
>
> Text objects are defined with `evil-define-text-object`. In Visual
>   state, they modify the current selection; in Operator-Pending
>   state, they return a pair of buffer positions. Outer text objects
>   are bound in the keymap `evil-outer-text-objects-map`, and inner
>   text objects are bound in `evil-inner-text-objects-map`.
>
> Common text objects like words, WORDS, paragraphs and sentences are
>   defined via a corresponding move-function. This function must have
>   the following properties:
>
> 1. Take exactly one argument, the count.
> 2. When the count is positive, move point forward to the first
>       character after the end of the next count-th object.
> 3. When the count is negative, move point backward to the first
>       character of the count-th previous object.

so after call text-object function for positive number,
which should move cursor to the end.
but only some text-object function move cursor to end,
so i define some advice to them:

```
(defun move-to-begine (region)
  (goto-char (nth 0 region))
  region)
(defun move-to-end (region)
  (goto-char (nth 1 region))
  region)
(advice-add #'evil-inner-paren :filter-return #'move-to-end)
```

`:filter-return` mean pass origin function output to advice.
then origin method by define `M-w` as `evil-inner-text-object-map` work.